# Beautifulsoup scraping list index out of range

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am working on a little personal project and have come across a little snag.  I am trying to scrape the full name of each player, their jersey number and their position.  I have succeeded in getting the list of URLs for each team roster and can get the first player (starting QB) from each team roster to print in the desired format with this code:

```
import requests
import bs4
from time import sleep

root_url = 'http://espn.go.com'
index_url = root_url + '/nfl/players'

def get_nfl_team_urls():
    response = requests.get(index_url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
    return [a.attrs.get('href') for a in soup.select('div.span-4     a[href^=/nfl/team/roster]')]
print(get_nfl_team_urls())

def get_nfl_player_info(nfl_team_url):

    response = requests.get(root_url + nfl_team_url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
    team_name = soup.body.b.text
    sport = "Football"
    league = "NFL"


    for tr in soup.findAll('tr')[2:]:
        tds = tr.findAll('td')
        jersey_no = tds[0].text
        full_name = tds[1].text
        position = tds[2].text

        return {
        "Name": full_name,
        "Team": team_name,
        "No": jersey_no,
        "Position": position,
        "Sport": sport,
        "League": league
        }

if __name__ == '__main__':

    nfl_team_urls = get_nfl_team_urls()
    for nfl_team_urls in nfl_team_urls:
        print get_nfl_player_info(nfl_team_urls)
```

However, I want all the players from each team.  When I try this instead:

```
import requests
import bs4
from time import sleep

root_url = 'http://espn.go.com'
index_url = root_url + '/nfl/players'

def get_nfl_team_urls():
    response = requests.get(index_url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
    return [a.attrs.get('href') for a in soup.select('div.span-4 a[href^=/nfl/team/roster]')]
print(get_nfl_team_urls())

def get_nfl_player_info(nfl_team_url):

    response = requests.get(root_url + nfl_team_url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text)
    team_name = soup.body.b.text
    sport = "Football"
    league = "NFL"


    for tr in soup.findAll('tr')[2:]:
        tds = tr.findAll('td')
        jersey_no = tds[0].text
        full_name = tds[1].text
        position = tds[2].text

        print {
        "Name": full_name,
        "Team": team_name,
        "No": jersey_no,
        "Position": position,
        "Sport": sport,
        "League": league
        }

if __name__ == '__main__':

    nfl_team_urls = get_nfl_team_urls()
    for nfl_team_urls in nfl_team_urls:
        get_nfl_player_info(nfl_team_urls)
```

It prints all of the offensive players from the first team, then stops and gives me the error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "nfl_player_scraper.py", line 42, in 
    get_nfl_player_info(nfl_team_urls)
  File "nfl_player_scraper.py", line 26, in get_nfl_player_info
    full_name = tds[1].text
IndexError: list index out of range

Eventually I would like to output these as JSON, but right now I am just trying to figure out getting the data.  I tried to store each player's info in an array and had the same error, but without any player info printing first.  Any help/tips are appreciated.

Comment: For the record, `for nfl_team_urls in nfl_team_urls:` is a bug waiting to happen.  Name your iteration variable something other than the thing you're iterating over.

Comment: OK, I actually noticed that and thought I changed it, but must not have saved the changes. Thanks.  Any ideas on why I can't get the data for each player?

Comment: There are indent errors in your codes. We need to guess what're your original codes like. Could you re-paste it? One suggestion, you can first increase indent of all your codes (many modern text editor support it), then paste in markdown format wont introduce indent errors

Comment: I think I fixed the indents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `for tr in soup.findAll('tr')[2:]` to skip the 2 head rows of the table. However, there are another 2 occurrences of head rows in the table (DEFENSE and SPECIAL TEAMS). After analysing the html, found better way to skip head rows:

```
for tr in soup.findAll('tr'):
    classtag = tr.get('class')
    if 'stathead' in classtag or 'colhead' in classtag:
        continue
```

At least before ESPN modify their HTMLs, it can work.

Besides, as roippi said, remember to correct `nfl_team_urls` in the last two lines :)